# Scrapy Scraping tag objects and aggregating values

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to learn how to do web scraping and scrapy seems like a good place to start. 
I figured out how to scrape basic text info from tags but now I want to scrape information from the tag itself. Below is an example. 
I am using this url: https://www.net-a-porter.com/ca/en/product/1100692/chloe/roy-day-small-leather-and-suede-shoulder-bag

and I want to scrape the name and price of the bag. when looking at the DOM structure there's 2 tags:

```
<h2 class="product-name">
<nap-price class="product-price" price:{...}>
```

I want to scrape the text value of the h2 tag and the price object inside the nap-price tag

and generate an object like this:

```
{
name: "from <h2> tag"
price: "price object from <nap-price> tag"
}
```

currently i can take the name from the h2 tag and I can get the entirety of the nap-price tag but how do I target just the price object? and then aggregate them into one object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `::attr()`, pass the name of the attribute that you want the value of. Then parse the JSON string to a Python object:

```
import json

price = response.css('nap-price::attr(price)').get()
obj = json.loads(price)

print(obj)
# {"currency":"USD","divisor":100,"amount":185000}
```